# Dynamically write in editor with Javascript

Tags: javascript, editor, visual-editor

Let's assume I'd like to add a button to the wordpress article/page editor.
The goal of that button is open a popup.

The popup should contain options to automatically write a *shortcode* in the text.

**WHAT I DID SO FAR (Probably incorrect)**

I opened an article in my wp-admin and in the browser console I was able to use this code to write content in the article

```
wp.media.editor.insert("[my_shortcode color='red']");
```

**WHAT COULD BE USEFUL**

It's obvious to think that user may want to change options, so I should read text again and replace 'red', with 'blue'.

Thank you

Comment: try `content = wp.media.editor.getContent();` If it doesn't work, give more details about where you use this code. I find strange to use `wp.media.editor` because it cannot be used if there is several editors on one page.

Comment: @mmm getContent() doesn't work, there's no such property in wp.media.editor...Anyway I'm about to add more details...thanks

Comment: then try `tinymce["editors"][0].getContent()` 0 is for the first editor if you have several on the page. and to write the new content `tinymce["editors"][0].setContent(content)`

Comment: tinymce.activeEditor.getContent() worked for reading, but setContent doesn't update the content...Maybe I could still use the code above to write...